# Question on a proof of Kuratowski's Theorem in Kechris's Classical Descriptive Set Theory

Tags: set-theory, proof-explanation, descriptive-set-theory, borel-sets

Currently I am reading Kechris's Classical Descriptive Set Theory.

> *Theorem $22.18$:* (Kuratowski) Let $(X,\tau)$ be a Polish space and $A_n\subseteq X$ be $\Delta_\xi^0(X,\tau).$
>   Then there is a Polish topology $\tau'\supseteq \tau$ such that $\tau'\subseteq\Sigma_\xi^0(X,\tau)$ and $A_n\in\Delta_1^0(X,\tau')$ for all $n.$

The following is a proof given by the author.

> It is enough to prove this for a single set $A\in\Delta_\xi^0(X,\tau).$
>   The proof is by induction on $\xi\geq 1.$
>   For $\xi=1,$ take $\tau'=\tau.$
>   For $\xi=2,$ both $A$ and $\sim A$ are $G_\delta,$ so Polish in the relative-$\tau$ topology. 
>   Put on $X$ the direct sum $\tau'$ of these relative topologies. 
>   So $U\in\tau'$ if and only if $U\cap A, U\setminus A$ are open in $A$ and $\sim A$ respectively. 
>   This is clearly Polish, and $A$ is $\Delta_1^0$ in $\tau'.$
>   Also, $\tau'\subseteq \Delta_2^0(X,\tau)\subseteq \Sigma_2^0(X,\tau).$
>
> Let now $\xi$ be a limit ordinal. 
>   Then $A=\bigcup_n A_n = \bigcap_n B_n$ with $A_n,B_n\in \Delta_{\xi_n}^0(X,\tau),\xi_n<\xi.$
>   Let $\tau_n',\tau_n{''}$ be topologies that work for $A_n,B_n$ respectively. 
>   Let $\tau'$ be the topology generated by $\bigcup_n (\tau'_n\cup \tau''_n).$
>   Then it is Polish and clearly $A\in\Delta_1^0(X,\tau').$
>   Since every set in $\tau'\cup\tau''$ is in $\Sigma_\xi^0(X,\tau),$ clearly $\tau'\subseteq\Sigma_{\xi}^0.$
>
> Finally, let $\xi = \eta+1\geq 3$ be successor. 
>   Then $A=\lim_nA_n,A_n\in\Delta_\eta^0(X,\tau).$
>   Let $\tau^*\supseteq\tau$ be Polish with $\tau^*\subseteq\Sigma_\eta^0(X,\tau)$ and $A_n\in\Delta_1^0(X,\tau^*)$ for all $n.$
>   Then $A\in\Delta_2^0(X,\tau^*).$
>   Apply now the case $\xi=2$ to $(X,\tau^*)$ to obtain $\tau'\supseteq\tau^*$ with $A\in\Delta_1^0(X,\tau')$ and $\tau'\subseteq\Sigma_2^0(X,\tau')\subseteq\Sigma_{\eta+1}^0(X,\tau)=\Sigma_\xi^0(X,\tau).$

The following are my questions on the proof.

> ($1$) In first paragraph, how to show that $\tau'$ is Polish and $\tau'\subseteq\Delta_2^0(X,\tau)$?
>
> $(2)$ In second paragraph, how to obtain that $A_n,B_n\in\Delta_{\xi_n}^0(X,\tau)?$ 
>   I can only get $A_n\in\Pi_{\xi_n}^0(X,\tau)$ and $B_n\in\Sigma_{\xi_n}^0(X,\tau).$
>
> ($3$) In second paragraph, why is it $A\in\Delta_1^0(X,\tau')?$

Comment: It is indeed clear that the sum topology of two Polish spaces is Polish. The sum of metrisable topologies is metrisable, ditto for completely metrisable. The sum of two (or countably many) separable spaces is separable. Read up a bit on the sum topology construction.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma Actually the confusion that I have on showing that $\tau'$ is Polish is because I do not understand the meaning of direct sum of topologies. By the way, I think that sum topology construction and $\tau'$ are different as former involves disjoint union.

Comment: Well, $A$ and $X\setminus A$ *are* disjoint. So if we use the topology as defined, it is just the disjoint sum topology on $A \oplus (X\setminus A)$, as usually defined.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma I see. How about other questions?

Comment: About (2) once you obtain the $\xi_{n}$ with $A_{n} \in \Sigma^{0}_{\xi_{n}}$ and $B_{n} \in \Pi^{0}_{\xi_{n}}$, you could define $\gamma_{n} := \xi_{n}+1 < \xi$ and use the fact that $\Pi^{0}_{\xi_{n}} \cup \Sigma^{0}_{\xi_{n}} \subseteq \Delta^{0}_{\xi_{n}+1}$

Comment: About (3), $A$ is a clopen in $\tau'$: We have $A \in \tau'$ since $ A \cap A $ is open in $A$ and $ A \setminus A$ is open in $\sim \ A$, and we have $ \sim A \in \tau'$ since $ \sim A \cap A = \emptyset$ is open in $A$ and $ \sim \ A  \setminus A = \sim A $ is open in $\sim A$. Since $\Delta^{0}_{1} =  \text{ clopen sets}$, it follows that $ A \in \Delta^{0}_{1}$.

Comment: @GabrielFernandes Thanks. Is it possible to write up an answer?

Comment: @Idonknow You are welcome. I don't know what is going on with the Polish spaces, that is why I preferred to comment instead of answering it. I will try to answer it in next days.

Answer (score 3):

Below when I cite a theorem a proposition or a page I am referring to the Kechris's book you cited in your question.

1. By thm 3.11 $A$ and $\sim A$ are Polish spaces since $A$ and $\sim A $ are $G_{\delta}$ sets. 
   So there are $ (A,d)$ and $(\sim A, d')$  metric spaces such that the topology induced by $d$ and $d'$ are the subspace topology of $ A$ and $ \sim A$. It is straightforward to verify, using $d$ and $d'$ that the sum topology $\tau'$ is such that $ (X,\tau')$ is Polish (this is stated already in proposition 3.3 without a proof, but see the comments on p. 3 regarding the sum of metric spaces).
2. By the definition on p. 68 there are sequences $\langle \alpha_{n},\beta_{n},A_{n},B_{n} \ | \ n \in \omega \rangle$ such that  $\alpha_{n} \in \xi $ and $\beta_{n} \in \xi $,  $ A = \bigcup_{n\in \omega} A_{n} = \bigcap_{n\in\omega}B_{n} $ and for each $n \in \omega$ we have  $A_{n} \in \Pi^{0}_{\alpha_{n}}$ and $B_{n} \in \Sigma^{0}_{\beta_{n}}$. Define $\xi_{n} = (\max\{\alpha_{n},\beta_{n}\} + 1) < \xi$, then $ \Sigma^{0}_{\alpha_{n}} \subseteq \Delta^{0}_{\xi_{n}} $ and $\Pi^{0}_{\beta_{n}} \subseteq \Delta^{0}_{\xi_{n}}$.
3. We have $\Delta^{0}_{1}(X,\tau') =\{ W \subseteq X \ | \ W \ \text{is a clopen in} \ \tau' \}$. We only need to verify that $ A$ is a clopen. We have $ A \cap A $ is open in $A$ and $ A \setminus A $ is open in $\sim A$, thus $ A$ is open in $(X,\tau') $. $ \sim A \cap A $ is open in $ A $ and $ \sim A \setminus \sim A $ is open in $\sim A $, so $ A $ is closed in $(X,\tau')$.

Comment: Who is Kechri? :)

Comment: @AsafKaragila thanks! I will edit that! :)